# How to reuse yield on spider

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, yield

I'm new to Scrapy and quite new to python also.
I have multiple `yield` with the same body within a spider.

```
yield {
    'url'  : response.url,
    'html' : response.css('body').extract(),
    'title': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
}
```

Each `yield` is inside different parse methods, but I would only like to write the `yield` once and reuse it.

I first tried a method takes response as an argument and returns `yield`.
Then I called that method from the parse method, but Scrapy claims that I cannot return `yield`.

Comment: i for one do not understand what your question is ... but perhaps you need to look up some tutorials on yield and what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a method for that code, eg:

```
def parse_item(self, response): 
    yield {
        'url'  : response.url,
        'html' : response.css('body').extract(),
        'title': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
    }
```

And call it from another method using `yield from`. Eg:

```
def another_method(self, response)
    # ...
    yield from self.parse_item(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this

```
item = {
            'url'  : response.url,
            'html' : response.css('body').extract(),
            'title': response.css('title::text').extract_first(),
        }

yield item
yield item
yield item
```